# Customizing search results template in Plone 4.3

Tags: plone

I'm trying to make just basic structural changes to the search.pt template (under portal_view_customizations — **plone.app.search/search.pt**). I load this up from portal_view_customizations, hit "customize" at the bottom, and make any sort of changes*. If I do a search on the page after altering the template, it prompts for a username and password.

I'm not getting any errors and can't quite figure out what might be the issue. Is there some workflow or publishing process I'm missing for within /portal_view_customizations? I've been able to edit other things within there like portlet templates without this issue popping up.

Thanks a lot. Non-urgent, but I'm perplexed. :)

*(by any change, I mean I went in and added just a class on the  around the brief description — no dice. Tried changing just some of the template text "filed under" after that, still nothing.)

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in p_v_c, I would report it here: https://dev.plone.org/

Comment: Roger, thanks aclark!

Comment: portal_view_customization is broken and is not always working. Here a useful comment of Maurits Van Rees: https://github.com/collective/collective.portlet.relateditems/commit/68755724249c042d7e6f3c4e158d8cace5b77549#commitcomment-3150652

Comment: Bug report is here, no update yet though: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13753