# Customize the search portlet in Plone for specific content types

Tags: search, plone, portlet

I'm using the search portlet in certain areas of my website, but I'd like to restrict the results to only search for a specific content type: for example only search the news items, or only show Faculty Staff Directory profiles.

I know you can do this after you get to the `@@search` form through that "filter" list, but is there a way to start with the filter on, so that the "Live Search" results only show the relevant results (i.e. only news items or only profiles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you know it already, but just to be sure: You can globally define which types should be allowed to show up in searchresults in the navigations-settings of the controlpanel, and then export and include the relevant parts to your product's GS-profile-`propertiestool.xml`.

However, if you would like to have some types excluded only in certain sections, you can customize `Products.CMFPlone/skins/plone_scripts/livesearch_reply`, which already filters the types, to only show "friendly_types" around line 38 (version 4.3.1) and add a condition like this:

**Edit:**
I removed the solution to check for the absolute_url of the context, because the context is actually the livesearch_reply in this case, not the current section-location. Instead the statement checks now, if the referer is our section:

```
REQUEST = context.REQUEST
current_location = REQUEST['HTTP_REFERER']
location_to_filter = '/fullpath/relative/to/siteroot/sectionId'
url_to_filter = str(portal_url) + location_to_filter
types_to_filter = ['Event', 'News Item']

if current_location.find(url_to_filter) != -1 or current_location.endswith(url_to_filter):
    friendly_types = types_to_filter
else:
    friendly_types = ploneUtils.getUserFriendlyTypes()
```

Yet, this leaves the case open, if the user hits the Return- or Enter-key or the 'Advanced search...'-link, landing on a different result-page than the liveresults have.

**Update:**
An opportunity to apply the filtering to the @@search-template can be to register a Javascript with the following content:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Let's see, if we are coming from our special section:
        if (document.referrer.indexOf('/fullpath/relative/to/siteroot/sectionId') != -1) {
            // Yes, we have the button to toggle portal_type-filter:
            if ($('#pt_toggle').length>0) {
                // If it's checked we uncheck it:
                if ($('#pt_toggle').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#pt_toggle').click();
                }
                // If for any reason it's not checked, we check and uncheck it,
                // which results in NO types to filter, for now:
                else {
                    $('#pt_toggle').click();
                    $('#pt_toggle').click();
                }
                // Then we check types we want to filter:
                $("input[value='Event']").click();
                $("input[value='News Item']").click();
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Also, the different user-actions result in different, inconsistent behaviours:

- Livesearch accepts terms which are not sharp, whereas the `@@search`-view only accepts sharp terms or requires the user to know, that you can append an asterix for unsharp results.
- When hitting the Enter/Return-key in the livesearch-input, the searchterm will be transmitted to the landing-page's (`@@search`) input-element, whilst when clicking on 'Advanced search...' the searchterm gets lost.

**Update:** 
To overcome the sharp results, you can add this to the JS right after the if-statement:

```
// Get search-term and add an asterix for blurry results:
var searchterm = decodeURI(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURI('SearchableText').replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1")) + '*';
// Insert new searchterm in input-text-field:
$('input[name=SearchableText]').val(searchterm);
```

**Update2:**
In this related quest, Eric Brehault provides a better solution for passing the asterix during submit: [Customize Plone search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811422/customize-plone-search)

Of course you can also customize the target of advanced-search-link in livesearch_reply, respectively in the JS for @@search, yet this link is rather superfluous UI-wise, imho.

Also, if you're still with Archetypes and have more use-cases for pre-filtered searchresults depending on the context, I can recommend to have a look at [collective.formcriteria](https://github.com/collective/collective.formcriteria), which allows to define search-criteria via the UI. I love it for it's generic and straightforward plone-ish approach: catalogued indizi and collections. In contradiction to eea.facetednavigation it doesn't break accessibility and can be enhanced progressively with some live-search-js-magic with a little bit of effort, too. Kudos to [Ross Patterson](http://rpatterson.net/) here! Simply turn a collection (old-style) into a searchform by changing it's view and it can be displayed as a collection-portlet, as well. And you can decide which criteria the user should be able to change or not (f.e. you hide the type-filter and offer a textsearch-input).

Comment: Thanks Ida! The if statement fixes the problem for sure in the live results drop down, but you're right, the results don't match up if the user hits "enter" and goes to the full search page. I'm hoping to combine your answer with SteveM's above and will post what I figure out after it works!

Comment: Hi Trish, I updated the answer with a JS-possibility to apply the filtering also on the landing search-page, because as you reported in  @@search cannot be customized currently via PVC( portal_view_customizations), HTH. Or could you find another way in the meantime?

Comment: That's brilliant!! Totally works, thanks so much Ida! I wasn't able to implement SteveM's still because I couldn't customize PVC, but I just tested your method and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad to to be of help :) Hope you've also seen the edit for the livesearch-if-statement and now there's an update to apply an asterix to the searchterm for @@search, too. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 3):

Watch how the query string changes when you use the filter mechanism on the @@search page. You're simply adding/subtracting catalog query criteria.

You may any of those queries in hidden fields in a search form. For example:

```
<form ...>
    ....
    <input type="hidden" name="portal_type" value="Document" />
</form>
```

The form on the query string when you use filter is complicated a bit by its record mechanism, which allows for some min/max queries. Simple filters are much easier.

Comment: Thanks SteveM! I think this would work, except would I then need two copies of the @@search page? Or I wonder if I could somehow target which hidden input line to add depending on where the user had come from. The weird thing is customizing @@search currently causes an error, which I think I reported as a bug already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039544/customizing-search-results-template-in-plone-4-3

Comment: You could definitely customize the input line to work differently in different site areas.

Comment: By just modifying the @@search page? Would it be similar to the "If context path is..." statement on Ida's answer?

Comment: Yes! That will do it.